# Помогите разобраться в разнице между очередями и стекам

Tags: java, коллекции, очередь, стек

Мне не понятна тема очередей стеков и вариантов из реализаций. Выжимка из того что мне удалось накопать в гугле выглядит как-то так:

**1.**

> Queue это односторонняя очередь - можно получить элементы в том
>   порядке что и добавляли.

**Вопрос:**
Вроде-бы `PriorityQueue` и `LinkedList` ее реализации в коллекциях java. А другие есть? Или по другому:

Можно ли сказать что любая коллекция которая дает возможность получить элементы в порядке их добавления это `Queue`, или только эти две?

**2.**

> Deque это двусторонняя очередь - очередь, у которой нет явно
>   выраженного конца и начала. Она может расти и уменьшаться в обоих
>   направлениях.

**Вопрос:**
Вот это совсем не понятно это по типу как замкнутый двунаправленный связанный список? Что это? Не понятна идея и какую проблему она решает.

**3.**

> И есть стек - тут можно получить только последний элемент.

**Вопрос:**
Вроде у `List` есть реализация `Stack` она вроде как отражает эту идею. А еще есть реализации? А какую проблему этот механизм решает?

Вот запутался немного, помогите разобраться что для чего нужно, и какие реализации имеет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очередь - это как конвейер. С одной стороны кладешь, с другой забираешь.

Стек - как обойма пистолета, что последним кладешь, то первым  забираешь.

Двунаправленная очередь - совмещает в себе очередь и стек.  Вы можете добавлять значения как в начало так и в конец, так же и забирать их либо по принципу стека, либо по принципу очереди, придумать "живой"  пример затруднительно, но затею можно понять, изучив методы этого инструмента. Это такой ящик с двумя отверстиями, в который вы что то можете класть и с одной и с другой стороны, так же и забирать. Например, кладем слева и забираем слева (как стек) или кладем слева, а забираем справа (как очередь) или с другой стороны подходим и делаем то же самое.
Наглядно, живая очередь стоит куда то в окно кассы и открывается другое окно, часть с конца переходит в это окно, причем последний в первой очереди самый хитрый и попал первым в новую очередь. Вариантов при взаимодействии двунаправленной очереди много и это один из примеров. В программисткой практике используется в асинхронной обработке, как вариант. Вообще может использоваться и как стек и как очередь, так же и комбинировать оба подхода.

К спискам (в них можно получить любой элемент) никакого отношения не имеет, в очередях и стеках можно получить только либо первый положенный, либо последний. Также внести можно только либо в начало, либо в конец. Элементы, находящиеся внутри стека/очереди не доступны, пока не окажутся на вершине (элементы попавшие туда до них не будут извлечены). Так же от списков отличает то, что если положить в список первый элемент, то сколько его не получай потом, он будет первый. В очереди/стеке при извлечении мы движемся по поступавшим ранее и извлекая первый, получаем все (в порядке поступления)

Нужны эти инструменты как некий буфер для временного хранения, в основном. То есть у вас поступает какая то информация, вы ее складываете в этот стек/очередь, а потом обрабатываете, либо в порядке поступления первые первыми - очередь,  либо  последние первыми - стек.

Почитать с картинками можно статьи, вроде [этой](http://javadevblog.com/pishem-ochered-na-java.html), здесь о самостоятельной реализации, но принцип хорошо описан "изнутри".

Comment: Спасибо очень наглядная метафора. А в чем разница между Queue и Deque, если продолжать метафору конвеера?

Comment: >>>К спискам (в них можно получить любой элемент) никакого отношения не имеет, в очередях и стеках можно получить только либо первый положенный, либо последний.<<< А как же LinkedList?

Comment: @Павел Да, LinkedList используется в Java для организации очереди, так как реализует нужные интерфейсы, но "по канону" очередью он не является, как раз из за возможности доступа в середину списка. Это такой комбайн с нужной функцией

Comment: Хочется поправить:

Comment: Queue(очередь) совмещает в себе функции Stack(стека), так как отличается от него лишь наличием ссылки на конец. Все остальное зависит от методов вставки и изъятия. Таким образом у очереди и стека изъятие происходит всегда из одного конца, разница лишь в добавлении новых элементов.                   DQueue(двойная очередь) отличается от Queue тем, что построена на двусвязном элементе, поэтому изъятие элемента может совершаться с любого конца. Ну и сохраняет функцию стека соответственно.  [push/pop можно сделать с любой стороны даже в стеке, вопрос только зачем, если это ресурсоёмко]

Comment: Поэтому их названия зависят не от методов, а от практики использования учитывая ресурсоемкость реализации этих методов.

Comment: А ресурсоемкость зависит от архитектуры. Стек и очередь - построены на односвязной цепочке элементов. Двойная очередь - на двусвязной цепочке.

Comment: Это так званые архитипы архитектуры по количеству связей. Кроме этого в различных языках существует масса разнообразий и искажений этих артитипов в зависимости от выделения памяти (единый блок или сегментированное выделение). К примеру, если память выделяется единым блоком - то доступ к элементам сверх быстрый как в обычном статическом массиве, а добавление и удаление сверхмедленное из-за необходимости выделять новую память и копирования туда результата. Поэтому если попробовать найти разницу - лучше открыть документацию и посмотреть конкретно реализацию, потому как запутаешься быстрее.

Comment: Тот же список(List) - это просто навороченный DQueue(точнее двусвязная цепочка) с измененными и добавленными методами, для использования в качестве редактируемого контейнера, а не в качестве конвейера.

Comment: Именно наличие двусвязной цепочки и сегментированной памяти позволяет без огромных затрат ресурсов менять элементы в любом месте цепочки. Далее разнообразие типов зависит от способа применения двусвязной цепочки для конкретной задачи. Эти типы обрастают дополнительными переменными и операциями, увеличивая потребляемую память на 1 единицу хранимой ячейки.

Answer (score 4):

Очередь Fist In - First Out (FIFO)

```
поставить в очередь -> ||||||||||||| -> извлечь из очереди
                       |           |
                       |            `первым пришёл, первым и выходит FIFO
                        `последний в очереди последним и выйдет
```

Стек Last In - First Out (LIFO)

```
поместить в стек -> ||||||||||||
извлечь из стека <- |||||||||||| 
                    |          |
                    |           ` помещён первым, но выйдет последним
                     ` помещён в стек последним, но извлекается первым LIFO
```

Здесь и далее элемент занимает в высоту две строки. (Что бы кто-нибудь не подумал, что это какие-то "параллельные потоки". Просто нужно разместить надписи к элементу в двух строках)

Deque совмещает достоинства очереди и стека, да ещё с двух сторон

```
поставить в начало очереди -> ||||||||||| -> извлечь с конца очереди
извлечь с начала очереди   <- ||||||||||| <- поместить в конец очереди
```

Игнорируем одну из строк - получаем очередь
Игнорируем правую или левую часть - получаем стек

Answer (score 2):

1) Есть и другие

> **All Known Implementing Classes:** AbstractQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue,
>   ArrayDeque, ConcurrentLinkedDeque, ConcurrentLinkedQueue, DelayQueue,
>   LinkedBlockingDeque, LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedList,
>   LinkedTransferQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, PriorityQueue,
>   SynchronousQueue

В javadoc обычно упоминаются все известные реализации интерфейса.
И как в той поговорке про утку, что ведёт себя как очередь очередью и является.

2) Нет, это не замкнутый двунаправленный связанный список. Имеется же два конца, один условно называется началом, другой концом. Такую очередь можно набивать и опустошать с обоих концов.
Хрен знает для чего это нужно. Но раз придумали, значит это надо для достаточно широко круга задач.
Например настоятельно рекомендуется использовать deque вместо stack (который считается устаревшим). Из [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Deque.html)

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. **This interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class**.

3) Ну собственно как уже написано в п.2, не то что существуют альтернативные  реализации стека, но даже рекомендуют их использовать вместо оригинального.